# Prolog print value as result instead of true

Tags: printing, prolog

I need to write a program, which returns a new list from a given list with following criteria.
If list member is negative or 0 it should and that value 3 times to new list. If member is positive it should add value 2 times for that list.
For example :

```
goal: dt([-3,2,0],R).
R = [-3,-3,-3,2,2,0,0,0].
```

I have written following code and it works fine for me, but it returns `true` as result instead of `R = [some_values]`

My code :

```
dt([],R):- write(R). % end print new list
dt([X|Tail],R):- X =< 0, addNegavite(Tail,X,R). % add 3 negatives or 0
dt([X|Tail],R):- X > 0, addPositive(Tail,X,R). % add 2 positives
addNegavite(Tail,X,R):- append([X,X,X],R,Z), dt(Tail, Z).
addPositive(Tail,X,R):- append([X,X],R,Z), dt(Tail, Z).
```

Maybe someone know how to make it print `R = []` instead of `true`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code prepares the value of `R` as it goes down the recursing chain top-to-bottom, treating the value passed in as the initial list. Calling `dt/2` with an empty list produces the desired output:

```
:- dt([-3,2,0],[]).
```

[Demo #1](http://ideone.com/mU3ZWh) - Note the reversed order

This is, however, an unusual way of doing things in Prolog: typically, `R` is your return value, produced in the other way around, when the base case services the "empty list" situation, and the rest of the rules grow the result from that empty list:

```
dt([],[]). % Base case: empty list produces an empty list
dt([X|Like],R):- X =< 0, addNegavite(Like,X,R).
dt([X|Like],R):- X > 0, addPositive(Like,X,R).
% The two remaining rules do the tail first, then append:
addNegavite(Like,X,R):- dt(Like, Z), append([X,X,X], Z,  R).
addPositive(Like,X,R):- dt(Like, Z), append([X,X], Z, R).
```

[Demo #2](http://ideone.com/9CL7rz)

Comment: Thanks, your answer shows, that i still need to learn some things in Prolog.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you call `write` inside your clauses?

Better don't have side-effects in your clauses:

```
dt([], []).
dt([N|NS], [N,N,N|MS]) :-
    N =< 0,
    dt(NS, MS).
dt([N|NS], [N,N|MS]) :-
   N > 0,
   dt(NS, MS).
```

That will work:

```
?- dt([-3,2,0], R).
R = [-3, -3, -3, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0] .
```

A further advantage of not invoking functions with side-effects in clauses is that the reverse works, too:

```
?- dt(R, [-3, -3, -3, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0]).
R = [-3, 2, 0] .
```

Of cause you can invoke `write` outside of your clauses:

```
?- dt([-3,2,0], R), write(R).
[-3,-3,-3,2,2,0,0,0]
R = [-3, -3, -3, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0] .
```